# c++ shared pointer linked list

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

what is the correct way of creating a linked list out of an array
The type declaration is the following

```cpp
template<typename T>

struct ListNode {
public:
    T data;
    shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> next;

    ListNode() { }

    ListNode(T data, shared_ptr<ListNode<T>> next) {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = next;
    }
};
```

the array structure is the following
[value1, index1, value2, index2, ... , valueN]
on even position goes value, next goes relative index of the next value in the array

example:
[1,1,2,2,3,1]

should create the following linked_list:
node(val=1,idx=0) -> node(val=2,idx=1) -> node(val=3,idx=2) -> node(val=2,idx=1) -> ...

My current buggy implementation is the following:

```cpp
shared_ptr<ListNode<int>> convert(vector<int> value) {
   vector<shared_ptr<ListNode<int>>> nodes;
   for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i += 2) {
      shared_ptr<ListNode<int>> node = make_shared<ListNode<int>>();
      node->data = value[i];
      nodes.push_back(node);
   }
   for (int i = 1; i < value.size(); i += 2) {
      shared_ptr<ListNode<int>> node = nodes[floor((i - 1) / 2)];
      int nextIndex = value[i];
      if (nextIndex >= 0) {
         shared_ptr<ListNode<int>> nextNode = nodes[nextIndex];
         node->next = nextNode;
      }
   }
   return nodes.empty() ? nullptr : nodes[0];
}
```

After returning from this function I have memory issues.
Any code or links will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, try `make_shared<ListNode<int>>()` instead of `make_unique<ListNode<int>>()` as you are using `shared_ptr` everywhere else.

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. Thank you for noticing. However it didnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to keep a pointer to the last element of your list, and incrementing it in each iteration of the loop.

```
shared_ptr<ListNode<int>> convert(vector<int> values) {
   shared_ptr<ListNode<int>> head;
   if(values.size() == 0) return head;
   
   head = shared_ptr<ListNode<int>>(new ListNode<int>());
   
   ListNode<int> *node = head.get();
   node->data = values[0];
   
   for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
       node->next = shared_ptr<ListNode<int>>(new ListNode<int>());
       node->next->data = values[i];
       node = node->next.get();
   }
   
   return head;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    shared_ptr<ListNode<int>> list = convert(vec);
    cout
        <<list->data<<" "
        <<list->next->data<<" "
        <<list->next->next->data<<" "
        <<list->next->next->next->data<<endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

output: `1 2 3 4`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the solution. I evaluated it - however, after giving it an input array of 100k elements - still after exiting from this function the exception is thrown: Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeb787ff8). For small inputs - there is no such problem.

Comment: _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY reference __get() _NOEXCEPT { return __value_; } - this is the line there the exception is thrown